# I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when I try to go to https://www.google.com

Tags: google-chrome, ip, lan

I keep on getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED whenever I try to go to https://www.google.com on Google Chrome. It hasn't worked on any other browser either. I was recently overseas, and it hasn't been working ever since I got back. I have cleared all cookies and cache. Only https://www.google.co.uk works so far. I have also disabled "Use a proxy server for your LAN" in Control Panel. This hasn't worked either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Please check your pc date and time also `chrome://version` copy this and paste it to your search engine.

[image]

[image]

Try update into v45

```
Setting > About > launch the update
```

Let me know if this help you

Comment: I have already changed this. I am in the correct time. It still doesn't work.

Comment: the internet time too?

Comment: please give me your detail version chrome?

Comment: @AniPandu go to setting  > About to check your chrome version

Comment: 45.0.2454.85 (Official Build) dev-m (32-bit). Is this v45?

Comment: Yes it is. How was the result?